# getting attributes from a hash/difference between '.first' and '[i]'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hash

I have the following class methods for `goal`

```
  def evals
    self.evaluations.order("eval_number").group_by(&:student_id)
  end

  def evals_for(student, i)
    @evals = []
    self.evals.values.each do |eval|
      @evals << eval.keep_if { |e| e.student_id == student.id }
    end
    @evals = @evals.reject { |array| array.empty? }.first
    @evals[i]  
  end
```

in the view, i'm calling the second method like this:

```
<% @student.student_group.eval_count.times do |i|  %>                                                 
  <td><%= goal.evals_for(@student, i) %></td> 
<% end %>
```

which returns

```
#<Evaluation:x>, #<Evaluation:y>, #<Evaluation:z>
```

if i change the last line of the class method to call `@evals[i].inspect`, i can see the data inside each hash, like so:

```
#<Evaluation id: 1949, score: 3, created_at: "2013-08-28 09:44:32", updated_at: "2013-08-28 09:44:32", student_id: 32, goal_id: 63, eval_number: 29>
```

I want to get the score, but when I call `@evals[i].score` on the last line in the class method, i get an error - `undefined method 'score' for nil:NilClass`

I know I can't call class methods on hashes, but is there a way to pull out just that data?  As a sub-question, I'm a bit confused about the difference between `.first` and `[i]` as calling `@evals.first.score` returns "3" - only I can't use first as I need to be able to access each instance of `evaluation` in turn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a simple Hash:

```
#<Evaluation id: 1949, score: 3, created_at: "2013-08-28 09:44:32", updated_at: "2013-08-28 09:44:32", student_id: 32, goal_id: 63, eval_number: 29>
```

It's an instance of `Evaluation` class so you should be able to call `score` on it. I think your issue is due to the fact that you are trying to call `score` on `nil`

You'll probably want to make sure that you have an instance object before calling the method:

```
@evals[i].score if @evals[i]
```